# HDD Raw Read Error Rate over limit

Tags: hard-drive, backup, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I've been trying to make a clone of this HDD for a day now, but it's been horribly slow. Someone recommended doing a `chkdsk` on the drive and then rebooting, but `chkdsk` was going way too slow as well—it was scanning sectors one by one.

I downloaded HD Tune Pro, and immediately saw that the Raw Read Error Rate was over the limit at 44 (42 being the worst).

What should I do in this situation? Is it now impossible to clone the drive?

[image: Screen shot of HD Tune health report]

Answer (score 0):

*Don't* run chkdsk and further stress a drive that might be failing! Create a Linux LiveCD/USB, download and run [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to recover data to a separate physical drive. Be sure to read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) first, and there are lots of tutorials on the net.

Depending on how much data is missing, if you're trying to clone your OS the copy may or may not work. You can try it, but I would recommend reinstalling your OS on the new drive, mounting the ddrescue image and simply copying your important data over.